# AngularJs Custom orderBy with two parameters

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble with the proper syntax for creating a custom orderBy filter.  I have no problems if require one parameter ( the item being iterator over in ng-repeat ).  How do you pass a second parameter.  I have tried:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:myCustomSort:mySecondParameter"></div>
```

However if I put a break in the myCustomSort function,  mySecondParameter is undefined.  Additionally can you have orderBy reverse the order as well and if so where do you stick the "reverse" parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to pass an additional parameter into the sort function.  Instead I  just created an appendItemFilter which takes the argument I wanted to reference in the customSort and appends it to each item.  Then I can just reference it directly in the item.
so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | appendItem:mySecondParameter | orderBy:myCustomSort"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of adding an additional parameter to the ng-repeat, you could declare a variable on the controller's $scope for the 2nd param and bind it to some kind of input on the view:

    $scope.sortBy = someParamToSortBy;  // ex: 'price', 'name', etc...

Then your custom orderBy function can just access the $scope.sortBy without passing in a 2nd param.

        $scope.mySortFunction = function(item) {
           return(item[$scope.sortBy]);
        };

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom filter to filter by multiple keys

In your js file:-

```
App.filter('multiOrderBy', ["$filter", function ($filter) {
return function (items, key1, key2) {
    var newItems = [];
    if(!items || !items.length)
        return newItems;
    function sortKey1(obj) {
        return obj[key1].toLowerCase();
    }
    function sortKey2(obj) {
        return obj[key2].toLowerCase();
    }
    if(key1)
        newItems = $filter('orderBy')(items, sortKey1);
    if(key2)
        newItems = $filter('orderBy')(newItems, sortKey2);
    return newItems;
  }
}]);
```

In HTML:-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | multiOrderBy: 'name': 'category'"></div>
```

In my case items are:-

```
$scope.items = [
        {"name":"ABC", "category":"Project"},
        {"name":"xyz", "category":"Project"},
        {"name":"red", "category":"Color"},
        {"name":"Blue", "category":"Color"}
    ];
```

so after filtering the array will be:-

```
$scope.items = [
        {"name":"Blue", "category":"Color"},
        {"name":"red", "category":"Color"},
        {"name":"ABC", "category":"Project"},
        {"name":"xyz", "category":"Project"}
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy. The parameter for the orderBy filter could be a string, function or an array. So you may write:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:[myCustomSort,mySecondParameter]"></div>
```

to sort your data by two properties.

As an example see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kFHXL/ if you click on the "Age" you can see that the data are sorted by name and after that by age.

Comment: Thanks but...Your example of a two field sort is NOT the same as a customSort function with parameters. As a matter of course, I always read the doc.   This fiddle is a direct example of my question: http://jsfiddle.net/4pcbc/.   Additionally,  your example pseudocode will not work...an array composed of a function and a parameter. Try it.